# R and HDF5 Troubles

Tags: r, hdf5

I am trying to load an hdf5 into R and running into some problems.  Here are the steps I took to configure my environment:

- R 2.10.0 (x64) on Mac OS X 10.6
- hdf5 1.8.3 installed via macports
- hdf5_1.6.9.tar.gz from CRAN

I suspect the problem I am having relates to incompatibilities in my version of HDF5 and the one the R module expects.  For completeness here is how I installed the R module:

> R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='CPPFLAGS=-I/opt/local/include' --configure-args='--with-hdf5=/opt/local' hdf5_1.6.9.tar.gz

This builds fine.  The library seems to load without issue, but no data is returned when I try to load a file:

> library(hdf5)
>
> hdf5load("test.h5")
>
> NULL

Yet,

> osx:data scott$ h5dump test.h5 
>   HDF5 "test.h5" {
>   GROUP "/" {
>      DATASET "dset" {
>         DATATYPE  H5T_STD_I32LE
>         DATASPACE  SIMPLE { ( 31 ) / ( 31 ) }
>         DATA {
>         (0): 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192,
>         (14): 16384, 32768, 65536, 131072, 262144, 524288, 1048576, 2097152,
>         (22): 4194304, 8388608, 16777216, 33554432, 67108864, 134217728,
>         (28): 268435456, 536870912, 1073741824
>         }
>      }
>   }
>   }

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but I just point out that the Mac build on R 2.10 failed: http://www.r-project.org/nosvn/R.check/r-release-macosx-ix86/hdf5-00check.html.

Comment: This is true, but it provides little reason why the build failed.  I manually built it without errors or warnings...

Comment: Without wanting to sound patronising, you are sure that hdfload is looking in the correct directory, aren't you?  I've come a croper with that sort of thing many a time.

Comment: I just checked to make sure and yes, I was in the correct directory.

Comment: Can you run the example in the help file of `hdfsave`? It works on my Mac (OS 10.6.2) with the same setup.

Comment: Hah, yes that works.  I feel foolish now, I did not expect that behavior.  Thanks for pointing me to that.

Comment: related? http://stackoverflow.com/q/4947112/199217

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `verbosity` argument in `hdfload()` and check your environment using `ls()`. `hdfload()` has a side effect, it loads the tables into the current environment, `NULL` is the default return value. If you use the argument `load=TRUE` the objects are returned as the components of a named list:

- `load`: A logical value. If 'FALSE', 
  the objects are returned as the
           components of a named list. If 'TRUE' (the default), the
          objects are loaded as individual variables with their own
          names - the function returns nothing in this case.

On my Mac everything works well with the same setup.

```
R> rm(list=ls())
R> ls()
character(0)
R> hdf5load("TestHDF5.h5", verbosity=3)
hdf5_global_verbosity=3 load=1
Processing object: Dataset0 ...... its a dataset...Dataset has ID335544326
Dataset has tid 201326902
Dataset has space id 268435467
Dataset has rank 1
Dataset has dims/maxdims: 1 / 1 
Allocating vector with rank=1 dim=1
calling vector_io. Hangs here with big datsets
Setting buffer size in plist
About to read with bufsize = 50
in string_ref: count=1, size=25 srcbf=25
leaving string_ref
 Done read
in vector_io: permuting
in vector_io: tidying
Phew. Done it. calling iinfo->add
Rank > 1 or not VECSXP
Calling  hdf5_load_attributes 
back from  hdf5_load_attributes 
...Finished dataset 
Processing object: Table0 ...... its a dataset...Dataset has ID335544327
Dataset has tid 201326906
Dataset has space id 268435468
Dataset has rank 1
Dataset has dims/maxdims: 1 / 1 
Dataset has type = VECSXP and rank 1
Reading...
....done
in string_ref: count=1, size=25 srcbf=25
leaving string_ref
...Finished dataset 
NULL
R> ls()
[1] "Dataset0" "Table0"
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also try the h5r package on CRAN. This package uses the new hdf5 libraries and provides more functionality than hdf5 library.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be on CRAN, found it on [r-forge](http://r-forge.r-project.org/projects/h5r/)

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. It is on r-forge. R-forge used to offer functionality for getting things on CRAN, but I don't know where that went.