# Invoke R on a server to extract data, from within R session on host?

Tags: bash, r, hdf5

### Background

I have an R script that runs on a host, and starts jobs on a server. The jobs output large hdf5 files.

The rest of my work is done on the host. However, the R hdf5 libraries only work on the server and not the host (because of a known [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4947112/199217)).

From R on the host, can I connect to an R session on the server, load the R hdf5 libraries, extract data from an hdf5 file, and then pass this object to the host?

### Current approach

My current kludge is to call a bash script from within R that invokes an R script on the server and does the extraction to Rdata files, and then use rsync to bring it back to the host (all within `system()`)

### Question

Is there a better way to extract data from these hdf5 files on the server?

I am thinking of something like entering a server R session in the same way that I can enter the `browser` session when debugging.

Comment: Do the HDF5 bindings work in other languages? If so, maybe use the h5py and rpy2 packages in Python to ship the data over to R.

Comment: @kwatford h5utils do work, although the R utils are easier (for me) to use and I would prefer not to have to rewrite the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about [Rserve](http://cran.ma.imperial.ac.uk/web/packages/Rserve/index.html), or there is a video of using [svSocket](http://cran.ma.imperial.ac.uk/web/packages/svSocket/index.html) for passing data between client and server on the [data.table](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/) homepage.