# How to deal with hdf5 files in R?

Tags: r, hdf5

I have a file in `hdf5` format.  I know that it is supposed to be a matrix, but I want to read that matrix in `R` so that I can study it.  I see that there is a `h5r` package that is supposed to help with this, but I do not see any simple to read/understand tutorial.  Is such a tutorial available online.  Specifically, How do you read a `hdf5` object with this package, and how to actually extract the matrix?

UPDATE

I found out a package `rhdf5` which is not part of CRAN but is part of BioConductoR.  The interface is relatively easier to understand the the documentation and example code is quite clear.  I could use it without problems.  My problem it seems was the input file.  The matrix that I wanted to read was actually stored in the `hdf5` file as a `python pickle`.  So every time I tried to open it and access it through `R` i got a `segmentation fault`.  I did figure out how to save the matrix from within `python` as a `tsv` file and now that problem is solved.

Answer (score 59):

The `rhdf5` package works really well, although it is not in CRAN. Install it from [Bioconductor](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/rhdf5.html)

```
# as of 2020-09-08, these are the updated instructions per
# https://bioconductor.org/install/

if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
  install.packages("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install("rhdf5")
```

And to use it:

```
library(rhdf5)
```

List the objects within the file to find the data group you want to read:

```
h5ls("path/to/file.h5")
```

Read the HDF5 data:

```
mydata <- h5read("path/to/file.h5", "/mygroup/mydata")
```

And [inspect the structure](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/str.html):

```
str(mydata)
```

(Note that multidimensional arrays [may appear transposed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18359783/r-hdf5-dataset-written-incorrectly)). Also you can read groups, which will be named lists in R.

Comment: Very good package indeed. I was thinking about using the `h5r` package from CRAN first but it seems underdocumented. If you don't mind depending on Bioconductor then `rhdf5` is definitely the way to go.

Comment: Can be helpful to use function h5ls("path/to/file.h5") before reading in the h5 file.

Comment: This is a good start. Here is a decent tutorial with detail on the use of rdhf5 http://www.r-bloggers.com/working-with-hdf-files-in-r-example-pathfinder-sst-data/

Comment: @Sam I don't understand what goes into the "/mygroup/mydata" part, where do I see that information?

Comment: @user4050 use h5ls to see the structure

Comment: this package works with compound datatypes (i had to install package bit64 first though)

Answer (score 24):

You could also use **h5**, a package which I recently published on CRAN.
Compared to `rhdf5` it has the following features:

1. S4 object model to directly interact with HDF5 objects like files, groups, datasets and attributes.
2. Simpler syntax, implemented R-like subsetting operators for datasets supporting commands like 

   `readdata <- dataset[1:3, 1:3]
   dataset[1:3, 1:3] <- matrix(1:9, nrow = 3)`
3. Supported NA values for all data types
4. 200+ Test cases with a code coverage of 80%+.

To save a matrix you could use:

```
library(h5)
testmat <- matrix(rnorm(120), ncol = 3)
# Create HDF5 File
file <- h5file("test.h5")
# Save matrix to file in group 'testgroup' and datasetname 'testmat'
file["testgroup", "testmat"] <- testmat
# Close file
h5close(file)
```

... and read the entire matrix back into R:

```
file <- h5file("test.h5")
testmat_in <- file["testgroup", "testmat"][]
h5close(file)
```

See also h5 on

- CRAN: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/h5/index.html
- Github: https://github.com/mannau/h5

Comment: Could you outline the most important differences between `h5` and `Rhdf5`?

Comment: how to load table from compound tables?
lat <- readDataSet(dataset["table"])
Error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) : 
  Reading of compound datatypes is not yet supported.

Comment: Does `h5` package support data frames?

Comment: `h5` has been depreciated in favour of  `hdf5r `

Answer (score 5):

I used the `rgdal` package to read HDF5 files. You do need to take care that probably the binary version of `rgdal` does not support `hdf5`. In that case, you need to build `gdal` from source with HDF5 support before building `rgdal` from source.

Alternatively, try and convert the files from `hdf5` to `netcdf`. Once they are in netcdf, you can use the excellent `ncdf` package to access the data. The conversion I think could be done with the [`cdo` tool](https://code.zmaw.de/projects/cdo).

Comment: Can you show me some template code on how to go about with this?

Comment: Your question right now is a bit broad. If you have more specific questions, including code examples, feel free to ask more questions.

Answer (score 5):

The [`ncdf4`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ncdf4/index.html) package, an interface to netCDF-4, can also be used to read hdf5 files (netCDF-4 is compatible with netCDF-3, but it uses hdf5 as the storage layer).

In the developer's words:

- the [HDF group](http://www.hdfgroup.org/projects/netCDF-4/) says:

> NetCDF-4 combines the netCDF-3 and HDF5 data models, taking the desirable characteristics of each, while taking advantage of their separate strengths

- [Unidata](http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/docs/netcdf/NetCDF_002d4-Format.html) says:

> The netCDF-4 format implements and expands the netCDF-3 data model by using an enhanced version of HDF5 as the storage layer.

In practice, `ncdf4` provides a simple interface, and migrating code from using older `hdf5` and `ncdf` packages to a single `ncdf4` package has made [our code](http://github.com/PecanProject/pecan) less buggy and easier to write (some of my trials and workarounds are documented in [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4954340/513006)).

Answer (score 0):

This solution Solve my problem:

```
# in Linux terminal
1. sudo apt-get install libhdf5-dev

#then in the R console write
2. BiocManager::install('rhdf5')
3. install.packages("hdf5r")
```