# reading data frame stored in HDF5

Tags: r, hdf5

I have a large data-frame (126041 Obs. of 604 variables). I'm new to HDF5 formats. I save the HDF5 file as follows:

`writeH5DataFrame(myData,"C:/myDir/myHDF5.h5",overwrite=T)`

1. how can I read the data frame back? there doesn't appear to be any `readH5DataFrame` or `loadH5DataFrame` function?
2. also, the `writeH5DataFrame` takes an incredibly long time, probably because of the large number of columns (604 in this case). The documentation mentions that "**the data for each column is stored in a separate H5Dataset.**" - not sure if this the reason for the long time taken. Is there any way to speed up writing a DataFrame in HDF5 format?

Comment: **Not every HDF5 file can be open in R.** Aren't you using MODIS dataset? HDF5 from MODIS dataset cannot be open directly in R (I am not sure though if it's because of the format or due to sinusoidal projection), you have to use some external tool to handle these files. See the **[MODIS HDF5 spatial data  tutorial](http://www.spatial-analyst.net/wiki/?title=Download_and_resampling_of_MODIS_images)**.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/15974643/684229

Comment: no I am not using the MODIS dataset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know which package are you using, but using `rhdf5` package, it looks very easy to write/read hdf5 files.

```
## uncomment the 2 lines after to install the package
## source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
## biocLite("rhdf5")
library(rhdf5)
## empty HDF5 file : the data base
h5createFile("myhdf5file.h5")
## create group hierarchy. : tables or datasets
h5createGroup("myhdf5file.h5","group1")
h5createGroup("myhdf5file.h5","group2")

## save a matrix 
A = matrix(1:10,nr=5,nc=2)
h5write(A, "myhdf5file.h5","group1/A")

## save an array with attribute 
B = array(seq(0.1,2.0,by=0.1),dim=c(5,2,2))
attr(B, "scale") <- "liter"
h5write(B, "myhdf5file.h5","group2/B")
## check the data base
h5ls("myhdf5file.h5")

   group   name       otype  dclass       dim
0       / group1   H5I_GROUP                  
1 /group1      A H5I_DATASET INTEGER     5 x 2
2       / group2   H5I_GROUP                  
3 /group2      B H5I_DATASET   FLOAT 5 x 2 x 2

 ## read A and B
 D = h5read("myhdf5file.h5","group1/A")
 E = h5read("myhdf5file.h5","group2/B")
```

Comment: I am using `h5r` package. The `rhdf5` package doesn't seem to be supported anymore. also, I am interested in saving a data frame rather than matrix or array (and converting a data frame to matrix before saving it is probably one way to go about it).

Comment: @uday [rhdf5](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/rhdf5.html) is actively supported; ask on the [Bioconductor](http://bioconductor.org/help/mailing-list/mailform/) mailing list.