# How to read HDF format in R?

Tags: r, hdf5, rgdal

I want to work with some data that has the format of hdf. I downloaded the file from here: 
I tried to open/read the file using different commands but I got  errors:
1

> h5ls(")

```
  2
```

> library(rgdal)
>
> Gdalinfo("")

```
 Error: could not find function "Gdalinfo"
 > GDALinfo("")
  Error in .local(.Object, ...) : 
 `' not recognised as a supported file format.
```

3

```
            > GDALinfo("" ,returnCategoryNames=FALSE)

             Error in .local(.Object, ...) : 
     `' not recognised as a supported file format.

        > a=readGDAL("")

        Error in .local(.Object, ...) : 
      `' not recognised as a supported file format.
```

3

> a=readGDAL("file.hdf")

```
       Error in .local(.Object, ...) : 
      `file.hdf' not recognised as a supported file format.
```

4

> GDALinfo(fname="file.hdf")

```
       Error in .local(.Object, ...) : 
     `f' does not exist in the file system,
```

and is not recognised as a supported dataset name.
5

```
      > GDALinfo(fname="file.hdf")

   Error in .local(.Object, ...) : 
      `file.hdf' not recognised as a supported file format.
```

I appreciate any-help and the file is can be downloaded thru the link I provided.Thanks

Comment: Download the file and check whether the size in the ftp directory listing matches the size on your local system. As for checksumming, usually running through `gdalinfo -checksum` is enough.

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725609/r-and-hdf5-troubles

Answer (score 4):

Which HDF library for R are using?
The files you try to open are `HDF4` files and not `HDF5`.
You can use [HDF5View](http://www.hdfgroup.org/hdf-java-html/hdfview/) to open the files.